# How can I remove the currency symbol from values in selected cells?

Tags: excel, vba

I export Excel files from a website. The exported files have number values with a currency sign before them in a number of columns although the number format of the cells is "General".

I want to remove the currency sign.
Another tricky thing is the headers of these columns and even the column indexes are not constant.

Is there a way to select the cells/columns and remove the currency sign  that can work on any Excel file I am working on? Is there an easier solution?

Example of the problem:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
Range("K2:M6").Replace What:="$", Replacement:=""
```

or if your prefer selection before:

```
Selection.Replace What:="$", Replacement:=""
```

(it's just as quick by hand: just press ctrl+h)

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub RemoveDollarSigns()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell in Selection
        cell.Value = val(replace(replace(cell.Value, "$", ""), ",", "")
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the quick reply, I tried this and it does remove the "$ "but the problem is a value like "$200,850.00" is becoming "200" after I run the script on the cell. Any idea why?

Comment: The `Val`-command tries to convert a String into a number, and a comma is seen as end of that number. Updated the code.

Comment: Add another `Replace` if you need `.` to be replaced by `,` afterwards, if your local settings need that (judging by your comment)